# Error opening Node.js .SLN on Visual Studio Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, visual-studio, sln-file

I need to work on a Node.js project in Visual Studio 2019 for Mac.

It has been worked on with Visual Studio 2012 on a PC.

When I open the .sln there's a red cross showing the error: "Load failed: Unknown solution item type".

What could I try or should I do to resolve this?

Is it possible at all to work on Node.js projects in Visual Studio 2019 for Mac?

Comment: Just curious if you found a solution for this?  I'm trying to run node js on Mac VS (not VS Code) and don't see how to do it.

Comment: @Valerie I did try several things and had a look at MicroSoft info, but didn't get it to work. It seems that the Mac version lacks functionality. I'm now using VS Code.